# How to continue processing after an error happens in RxJava 2?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a `PublishSubject` and a `Subscriber` which I use to process a (possibly) infinite stream of preprocessed data. The problem is that some of the elements might contain some error. I'd like to ignore them and continue processing. How can I do so? I've tried something like this:

```
    val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    subject.retry().subscribe({
        println("next: $it")
    }, {
        println("error")
    }, {
        println("complete")
    })

    subject.onNext("foo")
    subject.onNext("bar")
    subject.onError(RuntimeException())
    subject.onNext("wom")
    subject.onComplete()
```

My problem is that none of the error handling methods help me out here:

> `onErrorResumeNext()` — instructs an Observable to emit a sequence of
>   items if it encounters an error
>
> `onErrorReturn( )` — instructs an
>   Observable to emit a particular item when it encounters an error
>
> `onExceptionResumeNext( )` — instructs an Observable to continue
>   emitting items after it encounters an exception (but not another
>   variety of throwable)
>
> `retry( )` — if a source Observable emits an
>   error, resubscribe to it in the hopes that it will complete without
>   error
>
> `retryWhen( )` — if a source Observable emits an error, pass that
>   error to another Observable to determine whether to resubscribe to the
>   source

I tried `retry()` for example but it hangs my process after the error indefinitely.

I also tried `onErrorResumeNext()` but it does not work as expected:

```
    val backupSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    val subject = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    var currentSubject = subject
    subject.onErrorResumeNext(backupSubject).subscribe({
        println("next: $it")
    }, {
        println("error")
        currentSubject = backupSubject
    }, {
        println("complete")
    })

    backupSubject.subscribe({
        println("backup")
    }, {
        println("backup error")
    })

    currentSubject.onNext("foo")
    currentSubject.onNext("bar")
    currentSubject.onError(RuntimeException())
    currentSubject.onNext("wom")
    currentSubject.onComplete()
```

This only prints `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Have you *tried* `onErrorResumeNext`?  The documentation as you've shown is a little weird, but that sure sounds like it does what you describe wanting it do do... I think the disconnect is that the API assumes, if an Observable has failed, that it may be unable to advance to the next element; so it's written to let you provide a new Observable that continues the sequence; so you just need one that picks up where the error caused you to leave off, don't you?

Comment: `onErrorResumeNext` has a parameter and if I call it with the same `subject` I still can't see the remaining next values and the `onComplete`. If i add a new `Subject` it obviously won't have the subscriber I added to the previous one.

Comment: Ok, to you it's "obvious" it wouldn't have the subscriber, and to me if the error-handling function doesn't take care of that, then what exactly does the error-handling function do?  It is both named and documented as the solution to your problem, so again *have you tried it*?

Comment: Yes I tried but it does not work. `retry()` just hangs the process.

Comment: I didn't ask if you tried `retry()`.  I asked if you tried passing a new observable to `onErrorResumeNext()`.  But clearly you don't want help if it contradicts your assumptions, so good luck.

Comment: I tried `onErrorResumeNext`. It didn't work. I expected that `retry` will work but it did not work either.

Comment: Why the hostility?

Comment: `"If i add a new Subject it obviously won't have the subscriber I added to the previous one."` - not true. That's what `onErrorResumeNext` is for: it RESUMES the flow of items to existing subscribers, but taking subsequent items from a different observable. It does not dispose existing subscribers. `retry` will rerun the observable (on existing subscribers) from the start, which means you will probably get the same items again as you did before (it doesn't simply resume). `onErrorResumeNext` lets you pass control from your "bad" observable to a new one.

Comment: As I said (with the example above) it does not work. Go ahead and try it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to continue processing after an error, it means your error is a value just like your `String`s and should go through `onNext`. To ensure type safety in this case, you should use some form of wrapper that can either take a regular value or an error; for example, the `io.reactivex.Notification<T>` is available in RxJava 2:

```
PublishSubject<Notification<String>> subject = PublishSubject.create();

subject.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(Notification.createOnNext("Hello"));
subject.onNext(Notification.<String>createOnError(new RuntimeException("oops")));
subject.onNext(Notification.createOnNext("World"));
```

Comment: Is `Notification` is something like the `Either` type in functional languages?

Comment: Something like `Try<Optional<T>>` compacted into a single class.