# PublishSubject stops emitting after `onError()`

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

**RxJava Query** :

Hi,

I have a `PublishSubject<Boolean> subject = PublishSubject.create()`;

I am subscribing to the above subject and doing an API call after this :

```
subject.observeOn(IOThread)
    .flatMap(boolean -> getSomethingFromServer())
    .observeOn(MainThread)
    .subscribe(something ->
        showSomethingOnView(),
        error -> showRetryView();
    )
```

When an error comes like `UnknownHostException`, `SocketTimeoutException`, I am showing a retry button. On click of the retry button I am sending an event to `PublishSubject()`.

`subject.onNext(boolean Value)`;

But after the error comes, subject is terminating and no other events are getting forwarded.

On quick search I can achieve this using the `Notification<>` wrapper, but haven’t found a good way of applying it.

Here’s two links I found :

[This link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2858) mentions the use of `Notification`.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787419/how-to-continue-processing-after-an-error-happens-in-rxjava-2/42789772) uses Notification but wraps the initial type of Subject i.e. `Boolean` in a Notification. How do I wrap the Error and Response that I get from `getSomethingFromServer()` into a notification.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer from **Jake Wharton** :

"map `getSomethingFromServer()` inside the flatMap and add an `onErrorResume*` operator as well

the enclosing stream will never terminate then

`.flatMap(b -> getSomethingFromServer()
    .map(response -> WrapperType.success(response))
    .onErrorReturn(e -> WrapperType.error(e))
)`

for whatever `WrapperType` you want, `Notification` or your own"

Also from **Hussein Aladdin** : https://twitter.com/Hussein_Ala

" I haven't used `Notification` before, but what I would do is wrap everything emitted from `getSomethingFromServer()` with an event class. Events can have different status "Success", "Error" and so on, and then override the `onError` from `getSomethingFromServer()` to also return an event.
Finally you can handle the different cases in `onNext`

Event's a custom class that you would create and you can override the `onError` by doing something like this
`getSomethingFromServer().onErrorReturn((Function<Throwable, Event>) throwable -> new Event(Event.ERROR, throwable))`
"

So the trick here was `onErrorReturn()`.